# Convert Delimiter fille to JSON format using Dataweave in Mule

Tags: json, mule, dataweave, flat-file

I need to convert existing delimiter file to json format using dataweave in mule.

Sample Input:

```
Name~#~ID~#~Company~#~Address
SRI~#~1~#~Infy~#~Bangalore
Rahul~#~2~#IBM~#~US
John~#~3~#~SF~#~UK
```

Sample outPut

```
{
Name: Sri
ID: 1
Company: Infy
Adress: Bangalore
},
{
Name: Rahul
ID: 2
Company: IBM
Adress: US

},
{
Name: John
ID: 3
Company: SF
Adress: UK
}
```

But i am getting below output

[image: Output]

Dataweave Transforamtion

[image: Dataweave Transforamtion]

Comment: Why do you ask the same question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347572/text-file-with-delimiters-to-json-using-dataweave-in-mule

Comment: Is it valid to have a separator with multiple characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the following input (input.txt):

```
Name~#~ID~#~Company~#~Address
SRI~#~1~#~Infy~#~Bangalore
Rahul~#~2~#~IBM~#~US
John~#~3~#~SF~#~UK
```

And the following DataWeave code:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var payload = readUrl("classpath://input.txt","text/plain") splitBy(/\r\n/)

var header= payload[0] splitBy(/~#~/)
var data  = payload[1 to -1]
---
data map (item, index) ->
    {(item splitBy(/~#~/) map
    {   
        (header[$$]): $ 
    })}
```

The result is:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "SRI",
    "ID": "1",
    "Company": "Infy",
    "Address": "Bangalore"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Rahul",
    "ID": "2",
    "Company": "IBM",
    "Address": "US"
  },
  {
    "Name": "John",
    "ID": "3",
    "Company": "SF",
    "Address": "UK"
  }
]
```

I recommend an array as an output

Comment: Actually i forgot to mention i have ' # ' before Name field as well --just in the starting of the header. how to remove that.. i used another transorm message to do that

Answer (score 5):

Very interesting question you can use `readLines` function from `dw::core::Binaries` and then split by `~#~`. Remember to set your payload to `application/octet-stream` mimeType so dw will handle this as a Binary data and later you can use this snippet to parse it.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import dw::core::Binaries
var lines = Binaries::readLinesWith(payload, "UTF-8")


---
lines match {
    case [x ~ xs] -> do {
        var header = x splitBy  "~#~"
        ---
        xs map ((item, index) -> {
              (item splitBy "~#~" map (column, index) -> {
                  (header[index]): column
              } )
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I learned another syntax `x ~ xs` for the head and the tail of a list :D.  Ty Mariano :)

Comment: Superb knowledge machaval . its works on a click.. Can you help me to more about dataweave.. any links/docs. learned new key words and syntax ..:) Thank you again

Comment: can you help kindly-- Actually i forgot to mention i have ' # ' before Name field as well --just in the starting of the header. how to remove that.. i used another transorm message to do that